# npm install failing . how to install without error

Tags: node.js, angular, npm-install

[image]

Npm install is not completed due to some errors.

I;m expecting the npm install successfully completed and ran this local project.

Comment: Did you check npm version?

Comment: Angular CLI: 15.0.4
Node: 16.13.1
Package Manager: npm 8.1.2
OS: win32 x64

Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1500.4 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         15.0.4 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   15.0.4 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          15.0.4 (cli-only)


C:\Users\HMSPL>npm -v
8.1.2

Answer (score 3):

According to your error message, you need python installed.
You can install that from here. https://www.python.org/downloads/

Install python 2.7.1.

If this doesnt help, than post your package.json and your node version and the operating system where you run npm install.

And in that case, post again the error after you installed python.

also run

```
npm cache verify
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json // or yarn.lock if you use yarn
npm i
```

last will clean up your installation.

After installing python, in a new terminal. (important you open a new terminal)

```
python --version
```

Answer (score -1):

`npm cache clean` in your terminal and please check the version of the node and angular in your machine and fix the version which matches your project then again install the npm `npm i`